# What is the concept behind "text" withiin Haystack SearchIndex

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

In the example from http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

```
class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')
```

It says
"Every SearchIndex requires there be one (and only one) field with document=True. This indicates to both Haystack and the search engine about which field is the primary field for searching within."

Does this mean it is the same thing as a unique id when it comes to Solr ? 
It would be really helpful if someone can elaborate with a Solr document example/how it would look like in a query.

Answer (score 2):

You can add as many fields as you want in Haystack/ES, but the only field that will store the text used for search, is the one with `document=True`, and for standarization, the default name for this field is "text"

Another file you need to have using Haystack is

`templates/search/indexes/project/anymodel_text.txt`

And you will add in this file the model fields you want to search for text, this `anymodel_text.txt` file should look like:

```
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.description }}
{{ object.last_name }}
# Or any other field that belongs to your model
```

And this text will be stored in the field `text` you're asking for

---

- The fields you add in this `anymodel_text.txt` doesn't need to be in `search_indexes.py`, the fields used here belongs to your model, the original:

  *e.g.: If you have a file named description in your model, and you didn't add it in* *search_indexes.py, you can use it in your `anymodel_text.txt` to store the text of the original field in the **text** field of Haystack model*
- The fields added in `search_indexes.py` are for **Haystack** model, and don't need to exist in your model, you can add new fields. This fields will exists in the **SearchQuerySet** object when searching